# How to get the datetime for next time in c#?

Tags: c#, datetime, caching

I'm using IMemoryCache in my project and I want to set an absolute expiration time for a cached item.
I want to create an expiration time that is set every day for the next occurrence of some predefined times (more than one timepoint)

Example:
The expiration time is set to 09:00 and 18:00.

If the current time is 08:00, the expiration time is set to 09:00 the same day

If the current time is 17:30 the expiration time is set to 18:00 the same day

If the current time is 21:00 the expiration time is set to 09:00 the **next day**

Currently, there was only one specific time each day the expiration date was set to and I did something similar to:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.Today).Hours < expHour)
{
    cacheExpTime= DateTime.Today + expTime;
}
else
{
   cacheExpTime= DateTime.Today.AddDays(1) + expTime;
}
```

Comment: So what isn't working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this, putting all my expiry times into an ordered enumerable of `TimeSpan`. Please note I've not tested this code, so use at your own risk.

I'm also assuming that timezones aren't an issue, and that the enumerable will always have at least one expiry time.

```cs
    public DateTime GetCacheExpiryDateTime(IOrderedEnumerable<TimeSpan> expiryTimes)
    {
        var now = DateTime.Now;
        var isNextDay = false;
    
        // Find the first expiry time in the list which is greater than the current time
        // If there aren't any, set the nextExpiryTime to the first time in the list (next day)
        TimeSpan nextExpiryTime = expiryTimes.FirstOrDefault(time => now.TimeOfDay < time);
        if (nextExpiryTime == default(TimeSpan))
        {
            nextExpiryTime = expiryTimes.FirstOrDefault();
            isNextDay = true;
        }
    
        // If isNextDay is set, then we add a day to our current day
        // and return the Date plus the expiryTime to return the next expiry date and time
        return now.Date.AddDays(isNextDay ? 1 : 0).AddTicks(nextExpiryTime.Ticks);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple and readable:

```
public static DateTime GetExpirationDate(DateTime cacheDate)
{
    if (cacheDate.TimeOfDay < TimeSpan.FromHours(9))
        return cacheDate.Date.AddHours(9);
    
    if (cacheDate.TimeOfDay < TimeSpan.FromHours(21))
        return cacheDate.Date.AddHours(21);
    
    return cacheDate.Date.AddDays(1).AddHours(9);
}
```

Comment: This is fine if your expiration times are ONLY at 9am/9pm. Maybe you might want to change it in the future to be configurable through a UI, to change when your cache expires. Your code would have to be rewritten.